# Local file cache library with reference counting in Java

Tags: java, caching, reference-counting

I'm looking for a good/reliable Java library that provides a read-only file cache with reference counting, i.e. a file can only be evicted from cache when the cache hits it size limit and the file's reference count is 0. Searching the web, I found [DistributedCache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) from Apache Hadoop but:

1. I'm not interested in, possibly, heavy-weight distributed solution -- I just need to store files in the local fs.
2. I'm not sure whether I can extract only the cache facility from the Hadoop project and wouldn't like to rely on the large dependencies.

Due to these two, I'd rather program it myself unless a good alternative exists.
Any help appreciated.

Cheers,
  Jacek